# Win32 terminal: unexpected printing behavior

Tags: windows, perl, printing, terminal, console

Where do the additional empty lines come from when printing this script in a windows terminal?

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.10.0;
use Term::Size::Any qw(chars);

my $w = ( chars( \*STDOUT ) )[0];
my $string = "Y" x $w;

say $string;
say $string;
say $string;
say $w;
```

The output from the MSWindows console:

```
YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY

YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY

YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY

80
```

The output from the Linux console:

```
YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY
YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY
YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY
80
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Different terminals and terminal emulators/ consoles work differently if you write to the last column on the screen.

- On windows, the cursor goes to the the 1st column of the next line, thus creating an illusion of an extra LF being printed.
- On Linux the cursor effectively at an imaginary column to the the right of the screen. So when you send an LF  it takes you to the next line.

This program sleeps between writing the long line and the LF

```
    use strict;
    use warnings;
    use 5.10.0;

    my $w = shift // 80 ;
    my $string = "Y" x $w;
    $|++;   # flush buffer on every write
    print $string ;
    print "\n" ;

    print $string ;
    sleep 2 ;
    print "\n" ;
    print "Finished\n" ;
```

On windows you see the following while sleeping.

```
YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY

YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY

[bottom of screen]
```

Whilst on Linux

```
YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY
YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY
[bottom of screen]
```

There is probably more to it than this, but hopefully this will satisfy your curiosity!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of 'say' use 'print'. I think output will be same on both Linux and Windows.

Comment: I am interested in why the script behaves differently on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

> I am interested in why the script behaves differently on Windows.

Because the two terminals you are using are different programs.